# Probability of Getting Two Specific Cards in 7-Card Poker Hand, Using Ordinary Deck of 52 Cards?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations, poker

If we have an ordinary deck of 52 cards, how many possible 7 card poker hands are there that contain exactly one "2" and 1 "King"?

Originally, I was thinking of it as $$ \frac{\binom{52}{4}*\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{7}}$$.
However, I'm not sure that it takes into account all necessary combinations.
So now I'm thinking that maybe it is just 52*48*(44*43*42*41*40).  Does that seem correct?

Thank you in advance for any help that anyone can provide!

Comment: Not sure I am following your calculation.  There are four ways to choose a $2$, then four ways to choose a $K$, then there are $\binom {44}5$ ways to choose the five cards which are neither two's nor kings.  So...

Comment: For the numerator you are choosing (a) one $2$, (b) one $K$, (c) five non-$2$, non-$K$ 's. Multiply the number of choices for (a), (b), and (c) to get the numerator.

Comment: It is $\frac{{4 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}{52-4-4 \choose 5}}{{52 \choose 7}}$.  An alternative approach could be $7 \times 6 \times \frac{4 \times 4 \times 44 \times 43 \times 42 \times 41 \times 40}{52 \times 51 \times 50 \times 49 \times  48 \times 47 \times 46}$

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: [*hypergeometric distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ways.** The number of possible *hands* with exactly one Deuce and exactly one King is 
$${4\choose 1}^2 {44 \choose 5},$$
as in the numerator of @Henry's first fraction.
Evaluated in R as:

```
4^2*choose(44,5)
[1] 17376128
```

**Exact probability.** Then the *probability* of getting that outcome
is
$$\frac{{4\choose 1}^2 {44 \choose 5}}{{52\choose y}}
= 0.1298814,$$
as in his Comment. Evaluated in R as follows:

```
4^2*choose(44,5)/choose(52,7)
[1] 0.1298814
```

**Simulated probability.** This probability can be simulated with reasonable accuracy by looking at results
from 10 million 7-card hands. For simplicity in coding I have
simulated Aces (1) and Deuces (20), instead of Deuces and Kings. 
[Code numbers assigned to denominations are arbitrary as long
as there is no ambiguity in the desired total (here 21).]

With ten million iterations, the probability
should be accurate to within $\pm 0.0002$ in 95% of
such simulations.

```
set.seed(1234)       # for reproducibility
deck = c(1,1,1,1,20,20,20,20, rep(0, 52-8))
tot = replicate(10^7, sum(sample(deck,7)))
mean(tot==21)        # mean of logical vector is its prop of TRUEs
[1] 0.1299681        # aprx P(1 K & 1 D) = 0.1298814
2*sd(tot==21)/sqrt(10^7)
[1] 0.0002126748     # 95% margin of simulation error
```